# Variational inequality or partial differential inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control, variational-analysis

My understanding is that variational inequalities involve a scalar product and that equations are solved using duality relations. How come the following is a variational inequality? It rather looks like a partial differential inequality.

[image]

$L$ above is the infinitesimal generator of the underlying dynamic which is a partial differential operator.

The following is from a page in one of Bensoussan Lions books

[image]

Comment: I don't see any partial differentials. I see the boundary of $V,$ $\partial V,$ and the boundary of $D,$ $\partial D.$ Is there some context you can add here?

Comment: @Rollen (vi) and (vii) are, L is the infinitesimal generator of the underlying dynamic

Comment: The pointwise inequality in (vi) can be expressed as "inner product with all non-negative functions is non-positive" - maybe it's just that.

Comment: @Dirk it could be, yes.. kinda feel there should be a reason to call something a certain thing tho

Comment: Hmm, isn't it a reason, that you can formulate it like this? I may be wrong, but iirc, there is a larger theory for variational inequalities than for differential inequalities...Probably context from the source could help to explain the wording.

Comment: I think, that the answer is just: Variational inequality is the more common term. I looked up other sources on variational inequalities for optimal stopping, and "variational inequality" is just widely used (and not wrong - see above). "Differential inequality" is also not wrong, though… (but not as general).

Comment: @Dirk if one uses duality and weak convergences in proof then I suppose variational is the right thing to call it .. there is not proof in my text and so I dont what machinery is used. I understand your line of thinking tho and dont think it is unreasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope not to be too simplistic in the answer, but I share Dirk's point of view in the comments.

Variational problems arose firstly in the branch of Calculus of Variations, where to define a notion of derivative for general functionals defined on a normed vector space (or some generalizations of it) and to find local minima, one had to take "small perturbations" of the solution, trying to show the value of the functional increases. The main scheme of the variational method is indeed as follows: assuming that the optimal curve $u(x)$ exists among smooth (twice-differentiable curves), we compare the optimal curve with *close-by* trajectories $u(x)+\delta u(x)$, where variation $\delta u(x)$ is small in some sense. Using the smallness of $\delta u$, we simplify the comparison, deriving necessary conditions for the optimal trajectory $u(x)$. These methods are applicable to a great variety of extremal problems called, indeed, variational problems.

With the above paragraph in mind, I guess that every time we result in an inequality involving functionals that act over spaces of functions there is the temptation to see a variational method in it, hence calling it "variational inequality". I do not know what is $V$ in your case, but condition $(vi)$ is indeed showing a functional (or even more generally, an operator) acting on some function.

Just out of curiosity let me point out why calling variational inequality or partial differential equation inequality can be seen as the same thing: the **Dirichlet's principle.**

Dirichlet's principle states that, if the function $u(x)$ is the solution to Poisson's equation
$$
\Delta u+f=0
$$
on a domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with boundary condition
$u=g$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$,
then $u$ can be obtained as the minimizer of the Dirichlet energy
$$
I[v(x)]=\int_{\Omega}\left(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla v|^{2}-v f\right) \mathrm{d} x
$$

Hence you see how to solve a PDE or to be a minimizer of a ***variational*** problem is equivalent, for some specific functional $I$. As a result, when inequalities are involves, calling them *variational* or *PDE* inequalities is not so much different.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I am familiar with the "variational methods" i.e derivates of functional defined on functions spaces.

$L$ is a differential operator, giving us a new function and not a number.

"I guess that every time we result in an inequality involving functionals that act over spaces of functions there is the temptation to see a variational method in it" .. I dont understand why this is the case could you elaborate?

Comment: The last part which you write looks more interesting and could start looking like something of the sort that I added to the post above.. We, as far as I can tell, go from a PD-inequality to a bilinear form( a functional with two variables). This looks similar to the PDE to Dirichlet funtional that you mention..

Comment: For context, as far as I understand, we are looking for superharmonic funtions w.r.t a stochastic process which are characterized by the PD-inequality in (iv) hence we start with the PD-inequality and not some kind of derivative of a functional. However you seem to suggest that they are related somehow, which I dont understand how as mentioned. Again it is a Diff. operator which gives a function not a value.

Comment: Exactly, my guess is that, since in stochastic calculus of variations it is used to work with operators, this terminology is assumed here as well. For example, you usually have processes that almost everywhere take values in a particular space, different than $\mathbb{R}$, but then, a particular calculus of variations is developed in that particular framework. Just as an example, also in PDE one has to work with Bochner Integral, hence we do not have functionals any more, but the main object of study becomes an operator with values in some Lebesgue spaces. There is tons of literature dealing..

Comment: ... with caluclus of variations for stochastic PDEs. Just let me add here a reference (as an example) where this is developed for Hilbert space-valued solution: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82794179.pdf

Comment: Another name for it is Malliavin calculus. It aims to extend the mathematical field of calculus of variations from deterministic functions to stochastic processes, allowing the computation of derivatives of random variables. Hence you see that all what is done for functionals can be paraphrased for operators as well, in a different context.

Comment: Let me add a remark: the Dirichelet principle holds (with a different functional) for any elliptic PD operator. Hence you realize how these two fields are interconnected. Hope I clarified a bit: otherwise please do not hesitate to ask again!

Comment: I have a lot of work to do atm and so I cant dig deep into this at the moment. I'll hand out the 100 bounty but will have to ask some more question I think to make this clear to me.. in order to consider the question answered. There are no other answers and your answer has given some insight thus far.

Comment: Do not worry, I'll be here to help (or even in chat) to try to clarify any doubt you may have (if I can, obviously)!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! The relation in the Dirichlet principle is kind of non-trivial but if it is true then is some kind of explanation. By the way do you mean "(v)" and not "(vi)" in "but condition (vi) is indeed showing a functional (or even more generally, an operator) acting on some function."